# Feign + Ribbon request interception AFTER target host is choosen

Tags: netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

What I'm currently doing (which is very simple and convenient way):

```
Feign.builder()
.client(RibbonClient.create())
...
.requestInterceptor(new MyInterceptor())
```

But interception occur before ribbon actually resolve target host. 
Problem is, that one header that I want to add, have to be created based on the name of the target host.

Is there anyway I can manipulate headers after host is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found following solution for this problem. Instead of using Feign interceptor I use RibbonClient delegate:

```
Feign.builder()
.client(RibbonClient.builder().delegate(new MyDelegate())
...
```

`MyDelegate` extends `feign.Client.Default` class and overrides `public Response execute(Request request, Request.Options options)` method.

In this way I can access target host by `URI.create(request.url()).getHost()`.

Then I create new Request, add my header and run `super.execute(newRequest, options)` as the last instruction.