# Create a Custom Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am using Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon in combination with Eureka in a Cloud Foundry environment.

The use case I am trying to implement is the following:

- I have a running CF application named `address-service` with several instances spawned.
- The instances are registering to Eureka by the service name `address-service`
- I have added custom metadata to service instances using
  `eureka.instance.metadata-map.applicationId: ${vcap.application.application_id}`
- I want to use the information in Eureka's `InstanceInfo` (in particular the metadata and how many service instances are available) for setting a CF HTTP header "X-CF-APP-INSTANCE" as described [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing).
- The idea is to send a Header like `"X-CF-APP-INSTANCE":"appIdFromMetadata:instanceIndexCalculatedFromNoOfServiceInstances"` and thus "overrule" CF's Go-Router when it comes to load balancing as described [at the bottom of this issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/155).

I believe to set headers, I need to create a custom *RibbonClient* implementation - i.e. in plain Netflix terms a subclass of **AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient** as described [here](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide#implement-your-own-client-with-load-balancer-support) - and override the `execute()` methods.

However, this does not work, as Spring Cloud Netflix Ribbon won't read the class name of my `CustomRibbonClient` from `application.yml`. It also seems Spring Cloud Netflix wraps quite a bit of classes around the plain Netflix stuff.

I tried implementing a subclass of `RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` and `RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` which are Spring classes. I tried giving their class names in `application.yml` using `ribbon.ClientClassName` but that does not work. I tried to override beans defined in Spring Cloud's `HttpClientRibbonConfiguration` but I cannot get it to work.

So I have two questions:

1. is my assumption correct that I need to create a custom Ribbon *Client*  and that the beans defined [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client_by_setting_properties) and [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client) won't do the trick?
2. How to do it properly?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, so thanks in advance!

**Update-1**

I have dug into this some more and found [RibbonAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonAutoConfiguration.java).

This creates a [SpringClientFactory](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/SpringClientFactory.java) which provides a `getClient()` method that is only used in [`RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/blob/master/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/netflix/ribbon/RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory.java) (also declared in `RibbonAutoConfiguration`).

Unfortunately, `RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory` hard-codes the client to Netflix `RestClient`. And it does not seem possible to override either `SpringClientFactory` nor `RibbonClientHttpRequestFactory` beans.

I wonder if this is possible at all.

Comment: @spencergibb I really hope you can shed some light on this. I have read quite some of your contributions on Github and StackOverflow, and I think this is something for you. :)

Comment: You should post code. Overriding beans in SpringBoot config should work.

Comment: I updated the post. I cannot post code to stuff for which I don't know how it's supposed to work. Unfortunately this is not described anywhere, and I have been searching the entire web for a solution.

Comment: We don't recommend using the ribbon rest client, just the load balancer. We recommend `RestTemplate` or `WebClient` instead

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks. I am actually using @LoadBalanced RestTemplates and FeignClients that have Ribbon stripped underneath them. Ribbon is not visible from the outside but it is Ribbon-retrieved information I need (basically Eureka `InstanceInfo`) to set the HTTP header(s). How would one do that with RestTemplates, FeignClient or WebClient? Do you have any information about the internal wiring with Ribbon?

Comment: I think, basically my question boils down to: how can I inject the `ILoadBalancer`, `IPing`, `ServerList<Server>`, etc. instances created for a specific Ribbon Client in my application? In the documentation of `@RibbonClient` it says you should inject the `SpringClientFactory` and get the LoadBalancer from there. Yet, this class has no obvious access to things like `IPing` - other than calling getInstance(name, IPing.class). Is that really the way to go?

Comment: @spencergibb I have created a sample project that tries it - what I believe to be the way you suggested. [See here](https://github.com/TheFonz2017/Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Ribbon-CF-Routing). Can you please let me know if this is the correct way to "inject" LoadBalancer and other beans into one's application? 
Please also note the **Problem** section of the readme, since this "application-level" routing is not what my intention was. I'd rather retry requests done as a result of Ribbon detecting failures also get updated CF headers. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer this question myself, in case someone else may need that in the future.
Actually, I finally managed to implement it.

**TLDR** - the solution is here: https://github.com/TheFonz2017/Spring-Cloud-Netflix-Ribbon-CF-Routing

The solution:

- Allows to use Ribbon on Cloud Foundry, overriding Go-Router's load balancing.
- Adds a custom routing header to Ribbon load balancing requests (including retries) to instruct CF's Go-Router to route requests to the service instance selected by Ribbon (rather than by its own load balancer).
- Shows how to intercept load balancing requests

The key to understanding this, is that Spring Cloud has its own `LoadBalancer` framework, for which Ribbon is just one possible implementation. It is also important to understand, that Ribbon is only used as a load balancer **not** as an HTTP client. In other words, Ribbon's `ILoadBalancer` instance is only used to **select** the service instance from the server list. Requests to the selected server instances are done by an implementation of Spring Cloud's `AbstractLoadBalancingClient`. When using Ribbon, these are sub-classes of `RibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient` and `RetryableRibbonLoadBalancingHttpClient`.

So, my initial approach to add an HTTP header to the requests sent by Ribbon's HTTP client did not succeed, since Ribbon's HTTP / Rest client is actually not used by Spring Cloud at all.

The solution is to implement a Spring Cloud `LoadBalancerRequestTransformer` which (contrary to its name) is a request interceptor.

My solution uses the following implementation:

```
public class CFLoadBalancerRequestTransformer implements LoadBalancerRequestTransformer {
    public static final String CF_APP_GUID = "cfAppGuid";
    public static final String CF_INSTANCE_INDEX = "cfInstanceIndex";
    public static final String ROUTING_HEADER = "X-CF-APP-INSTANCE";

    @Override
    public HttpRequest transformRequest(HttpRequest request, ServiceInstance instance) {

        System.out.println("Transforming Request from LoadBalancer Ribbon).");

        // First: Get the service instance information from the lower Ribbon layer.
        //        This will include the actual service instance information as returned by Eureka. 
        RibbonLoadBalancerClient.RibbonServer serviceInstanceFromRibbonLoadBalancer = (RibbonLoadBalancerClient.RibbonServer) instance;

        // Second: Get the the service instance from Eureka, which is encapsulated inside the Ribbon service instance wrapper.
        DiscoveryEnabledServer serviceInstanceFromEurekaClient = (DiscoveryEnabledServer) serviceInstanceFromRibbonLoadBalancer.getServer();

        // Finally: Get access to all the cool information that Eureka provides about the service instance (including metadata and much more).
        //          All of this is available for transforming the request now, if necessary.
        InstanceInfo instanceInfo = serviceInstanceFromEurekaClient.getInstanceInfo();

        // If it's only the instance metadata you are interested in, you can also get it without explicitly down-casting as shown above.  
        Map<String, String> metadata = instance.getMetadata();
        System.out.println("Instance: " + instance);

        dumpServiceInstanceInformation(metadata, instanceInfo);

        if (metadata.containsKey(CF_APP_GUID) && metadata.containsKey(CF_INSTANCE_INDEX)) {
            final String headerValue = String.format("%s:%s", metadata.get(CF_APP_GUID), metadata.get(CF_INSTANCE_INDEX));

            System.out.println("Returning Request with Special Routing Header");
            System.out.println("Header Value: " + headerValue);

            // request.getHeaders might be immutable, so we return a wrapper that pretends to be the original request.
            // and that injects an extra header.
            return new CFLoadBalancerHttpRequestWrapper(request, headerValue);
        }

        return request;
    }

    /**
     * Dumps metadata and InstanceInfo as JSON objects on the console.
     * @param metadata the metadata (directly) retrieved from 'ServiceInstance'
     * @param instanceInfo the instance info received from the (downcast) 'DiscoveryEnabledServer' 
     */
    private void dumpServiceInstanceInformation(Map<String, String> metadata, InstanceInfo instanceInfo) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json;
        try {
            json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(metadata);
            System.err.println("-- Metadata: " );
            System.err.println(json);

            json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(instanceInfo);
            System.err.println("-- InstanceInfo: " );
            System.err.println(json);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Wrapper class for an HttpRequest which may only return an
     * immutable list of headers. The wrapper immitates the original 
     * request and will return the original headers including a custom one
     * added when getHeaders() is called. 
     */
    private class CFLoadBalancerHttpRequestWrapper implements HttpRequest {

        private HttpRequest request;
        private String headerValue;

        CFLoadBalancerHttpRequestWrapper(HttpRequest request, String headerValue) {
            this.request = request;
            this.headerValue = headerValue;
        }

        @Override
        public HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.putAll(request.getHeaders());
            headers.add(ROUTING_HEADER, headerValue);
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        public String getMethodValue() {
            return request.getMethodValue();
        }

        @Override
        public URI getURI() {
            return request.getURI();
        }
    }  
}
```

The class is looking for the information required for setting the [CF App Instance Routing](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing) header in the service instance metadata returned by Eureka.

That information is

- The GUID of the CF application that implements the service and of which several instances exist for load balancing.
- The index of the service / application instance that the request should be routed to.

You need to provide that in the `application.yml` of your **service** like so:

```
eureka:
  instance: 
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]:localhost}
    metadata-map:
      # Adding information about the application GUID and app instance index to 
      # each instance metadata. This will be used for setting the X-CF-APP-INSTANCE header
      # to instruct Go-Router where to route.
      cfAppGuid:       ${vcap.application.application_id}
      cfInstanceIndex: ${INSTANCE_INDEX}

  client: 
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://eureka-server.<your cf domain>/eureka
```

Finally, you need to register the `LoadBalancerRequestTransformer` implementation in the Spring configuration of your **service consumers** (which use Ribbon under the hood):

```
@Bean
public LoadBalancerRequestTransformer customRequestTransformer() {
  return new CFLoadBalancerRequestTransformer();
}
```

As a result, if you use a `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate` in your service consumer, the template will call Ribbon to make a choice on the service instance to send the request to, will send the request and the interceptor will inject the routing header. Go-Router will route the request to the exact instance that was specified in the routing header and not perform any additional load balancing that would interfere with Ribbon's choice.
In case a retry were necessary (against the same or one or more next instances), the interceptor would again inject the according routing header - this time for a potentially different service instance selected by Ribbon.
This allows you to use Ribbon effectively as the load balancer and de-facto disable load balancing of Go-Router, demoting it to a mere proxy. The benefit being that Ribbon is something you can influence (programmatically) whereas you have little to no influence over Go-Router.

Note: this was tested for `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate`'s and works. 
However, for `@FeignClient`s it does not work this way.
The closest I have come to solving this for Feign is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962233/feign-ribbon-request-interception-after-target-host-is-choosen), however, the solution described there uses an interceptor that does not get access to the (Ribbon-)selected service instance, thus not allowing access to the required metadata.
Haven't found a solution so far for `FeignClient`.