# RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor not being called

Tags: java, spring, load-balancing, feign, netflix-ribbon

I am using `@FeignClient` (backed with Ribbon as LB and and Eureka as a service registry).
I would like to write an interceptor that gets called when load-balancing requests are sent out.

I found `RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor` from Spring Cloud but cannot make it being called.

I am using the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter({RibbonAutoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureBefore({LoadBalancerAutoConfiguration.RetryInterceptorAutoConfiguration.class})
class InterceptorConfig {
    @Bean
    public RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor ribbonInterceptor(LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient, 
                                                          LoadBalancerRetryProperties properties,
                                                          LoadBalancerRequestFactory requestFactory,
                                                          LoadBalancedRetryFactory loadBalancedRetryFactory) {
        return new RibbonRetryInterceptor(loadBalancerClient, properties, requestFactory, loadBalancedRetryFactory);
    }
}
```

`RibbonRetryInterceptor` is my implementation and looks as follows:

```java
public class RibbonRetryInterceptor extends RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor {

    public RibbonRetryInterceptor(LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer, LoadBalancerRetryProperties lbProperties,
            LoadBalancerRequestFactory requestFactory, LoadBalancedRetryFactory lbRetryFactory) {
        super(loadBalancer, lbProperties, requestFactory, lbRetryFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Intercepting the request...");
        return super.intercept(request, body, execution);
    }
}
```

**The intercept method is never called.**

I am using Spring Cloud BOM Greenwich.RELEASE, here is my `pom.xml``

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>address.service.client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>address.service.client</name>
    <url>http://www.acme.com</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for health checks and info pages advertised by the service 
            and read by Eureka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required to enable hystrix / circuit breaking -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For use of Feign client for HTTP / REST requests. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Required for Ribbon-Loadbalanced REST Templates to do retries. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- For custom Ribbon Client Implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: `RetryLoadBalancerInterceptor` only applies to `RestTemplate`. it does not apply to feign at all.

Comment: Thanks I have noticed that. How would one do it for Feign?

Comment: I'm not sure there is for feign. I can't see anything in here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/tree/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/ribbon

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to accomplish, can you elaborate?  There is a retryable load balancer in feign that should be used as long as spring-retry is on the classpath https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/ribbon/RetryableFeignLoadBalancer.java

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for asking. I would like to intercept load balancing requests (including retry-requests that are the result of Ribbon's retry settings and policies). I want to intercept them to inject a header in the request according to [CF App Instance Routing](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/http-routing.html#app-instance-routing). Thus I could tell Go-Router on CF to route to the instances Ribbon selected (overruling Go-Router). The header contains service instance info (appGUID / instance index) - which I add to metadata and get inside `InstanceInfo` from Eureka.

Comment: Therefore, I need an interceptor for load balancing requests, that gets a) the HTTP request and b) the (Ribbon-)selected Service Instance.
Something like this exists for `@LoadBalanced RestTemplates` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151079/create-a-custom-spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-client) I created and answered) but I could not find it for `FeignClient`.

Ultimately, by injecting the header, I could make use of Ribbon as a load balancer even in a CF-deployment - I could tell Go-Router explicitly where to Route requests and de-facto disable its own load balancer.